# batch %var:*\% to eliminate all before last \ not first

Tags: batch-file, var, directory, subdirectory

```
set var=C:\Users\user\Desktop\bla\bla.exe
set var=%var:*\%
echo %var%
```

this returns Users\user\Desktop\bla\bla.exe - is there any way to make it focus on the last \ and not the first one so that it would just return bla.exe? bear in mind that this will be used on multiple files and folders so i won't always know how many sub-folders there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet shows one way to do it.

```
    @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    @echo off

:main
    set var=C:\Users\user\Desktop\blah blah\yada yada.exe
    call :basename result "%var%"
    echo %result%

    endlocal
    goto :eof

:basename
    set %1=%~nx2
    goto :eof
```

It basically calls a function `basename` (named after the UNIX utility), passing the full name and the variable you want to assign the base name to, and you need to make sure you quote it properly lest filenames containing spaces will cause you problems.

The full set of variable modifiers can be seen in the `call /?` help output.

---

Alternatively, you can use the same `basename` functionality in a one-liner `for` statement:

```
for /f "delims=" %%I in ("%var%") do set result=%%~nxI
```

This allows you to get the base name *without* having to call a function. I tend to prefer the function myself since it's more readable but you could probably alleviate that by just including a comment:

```
rem Get base name of var into result:
rem eg: var    = C:\Users\user\Desktop\blah blah\yada yada.exe
rem     result = yada yada.exe

for /f "delims=" %%I in ("%var%") do set result=%%~nxI
```

Comment: this was the simplest of the 2 and I see how it works, but I switched to using a for in dir loop

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "var=C:\Users\user\Desktop\blah blah\bla.exe"
FOR %%a IN ("%var%") DO (
 SET "filename=%%~nxa"
 FOR %%b in ("%%~dpa.") DO SET "lastleaf=%%~nxb"
)
ECHO filename is "%filename%"
ECHO lastleaf is "%lastleaf%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Normally, the next question is about how to obtain the last leaf of the directory-tree. No subroutines required...

Note positioning of quotes to minimise problems with separators. ALso minor directory name-change to exhibit differences.